# statistical significance among three distributions in R

Tags: r, statistical-significance

I have three probability distributions (see graph). How can I test if they are statistically different from one another in R? Also, how could I test if one distribution (the purple one) is different than the other two combined?

Distributions:

[image]

Comment: I've voted to have this moved to [stats.se], since it's about statistical methods rather than programming, but I have a feeling they'll want a lot more information in order to help

Comment: They are very clearly different from one another. In my opinion, there is no need to test for a difference.  Moreover, if these represent posterior densities, then a test isn't appropriate.

Comment: If you have samples from the posterior, just report the mean and a credible interval.  They are very clearly different and a statistical hypothesis test will not give you any new information.

Comment: "Significant" is not an appropriate term to use in a Bayesian analysis. "statistically significant" refers to frequentest procedures.  I'm not able to walk you through the analysis at the moment, so I recommend you take another look at posterior summarization and Bayesian conceptions of probability.

Answer (score 1):

You very likely have samples from the posterior. Each of these distributions likely belong to random variables of a model.

If you wish to know $P(\text{orange}>\text{purple})$ you can compare the samples directly.  Here is an example

```
#Example
orange = rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
purple = rnorm(1000, 2, 1)

prob = mean(orange>purple)
```

This yields a probabalistic estimate that $P(\text{orange}>\text{purple})$.

Comment: what about two distributions vs 1 distribution based on my example?

Comment: Do you have samples from those distributions?

Comment: yes, the entire probability distribution for a given parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you have the mean and the variance for each distribution you should be able to conduct a t-test which is ideal for seeing if you distribution's tails overlap the critical value, in which case H0 cannot be rejected and both distributions belong to the same population

Comment: There is no need for a t test; these are posterior distributions.  They can be compared directly.